# How to Debug pio train in Predictionio?

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, collaborative-filtering, predictionio

Currently, i learn **[Recommendation Engine Template](https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-recommendation)**. However, by learn from existing engine, i need to debug All Scala's variable (input and output) when running `pio train`, is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Develop Predictionio Template in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494530/how-to-develop-predictionio-template-in-windows)